# Toggle/switch off notifications from ionic app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic2, ionic3

Is there a way to go in device settings and notifications for an app?
I want to have switch in my ionic app for push notifications where users can disable or enable the notifications.

I know the common way is that once you toggle off, it goes under device settings and you need to make a choice there.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using the latest version of ionic, then based on the documentation [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push/), then you can *unsubscribe* from the **PushObject** instance, to disable notifications or even devices, based on some conditional statement which you would attach to an interface. Example:

```
const pushObject: PushObject = this.push.init(options);

if (userWantsNotifications) {
   pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((notification: any) => console.log('Received a notification', notification));
} else {
  this.push.unregister(() => console.log('success'));
}
```

You can view more info on the cordova plugin [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/API.md#pushunregistersuccesshandler-errorhandler-topics) if this isn't exactly what you meant by turning off notifications.